# Is there any way to insert a php variable in the getElementById statement of javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have an input type elements whose id is automatically assigned by a wordpress php loop, i would like to know if i can insert this value as a variable in javascript getElementById statement to intercept the selected input field based on the id generated by the loop

[Screen of input element with dynamic id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH0z2.png)
[Screen of generated id in front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRNWP.png)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. Can you [edit] to show the JS code you've got so far, and explain what you want to change about it? (Also, please don't post pictures of text, just paste in the text itself.)

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)